# how to insert data in one form and displaying data in gridview in next or another form using C#

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

The form1 class is:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public static string passingtext;
    public bool click = true;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    Form2 form2;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form2.passThisValuetoDgv(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text); // pass this value to form2
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form2 = new Form2(this);
        if (click) //to avoid open a multiple form...
        {
            form2.Show(); //i change from form2.Showdialog() so that you can make a data entry...
            click = false;
        }
```

The form 2 class is:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private Form1 form1;

    public Form2(Form1 form2)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.form1 = form2;
    }
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\acE\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
    DataTable dt;
    public void AddGridViewRows(string id, string name)
    {
        dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add("id");
  dt.Columns.Add("name");
  dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

  dt.Rows.Add(id);
  dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value = name;

    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    public void disp_data()
    {
        cn.Open();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        cn.Close();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 2;
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "id";
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "name";
        disp_data();
    }
    string[] row;
    public void passThisValuetoDgv(string id, string name)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)) //if values are not null...
        {
            row = new string[] { id, name }; //new inserted row...

        }
    }

    //handle this event so that you can still open this form after close... 


    public string passvalue { get; set; }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form1.click = true;
    }
```

Comment: Please add a question to your question. What is the problem? What happens? What should happen?

Comment: @JonnyHenly likely not - new user. AcEm Kc, Please tag your questions with appropriate tags **only**

Answer (score 0):

Your passing text is already static, all you have to do is `string text = Form1.passingtext;`

You are also passing in Form1 into Form2 and sense the `passingtext` in Form1 is static you are unable to access it by using the name of the object you made of Form1.

To fix this ether remove the static and us `form1Object.passingtext` Or keep the static and don't pass in Form1 into Form2 and do `Form1.passingtext`

Comment: can u please write whole code for this ..is show error in my code.

Comment: Will do when I get a break today